# Webstorm SystemJS import resolve error

Tags: javascript, webstorm, ecmascript-6, systemjs

SystemJS makes it possible to specify what kind of content is rendered from the imported files:

- CSS `System.import('my/file.css!')`
- Image `System.import('some/image.png!image')`
- JSON `System.import('some/data.json!').then(function(json){})`
- Text `System.import('some/text.txt!text').then(function(text) {})`

([Source](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs#plugins))

---

Using SystemJS, importing from a file with a type appended, gives an error in Webstorm.
So when I do this:

```
import template from './404.template.html!text';
```

meaning I need the html file in plain text, Webstorm shows an error saying:

> Cannot resolve file '404.template.html!text'

showing red underlines throughout all of my project file structure tree.

How can I get Webstorm to only resolve the part **before** the `!`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After submitting an bug report on the JetBrains issue tracker, I got an answer which suggested that I should:

> Change JavaScript language version to `JSX harmony` in
>   `Settings` > `Languages & Frameworks` > `JavaScript`

Mine was on `ECMAScript 6` which I thought was the right one...

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately setting to `JSX Harmony` no longer works in WebStorm 11.